# Gradle sync failed in Android 1.5.1 userguide access denied

Tags: android

While opening Android Studio on windows machine I am facing an issue as follows

```
Gradle sync failed: ...\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.8-all\ah86jmo43de9lfa8xg9ux3c4h\gradle-2.8\docs\userguide\userguide.pdf (Access is denied)
```

I went to the folder and checked the file, it exists and it has all permissions. May I know What I am missing here or how to get rid of this issue.

Comment: look here, may that´s the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468075/android-studio-beta-failed-project-refresh-access-is-denied

Comment: It's worth running Android Studio as administrator, just to see if it gets around the problem, and to help you diagnose.

Comment: I have tried both options but no luck

Comment: Is that file location synched with dropbox, Google drive etc?

Comment: No it' s on local drive

Comment: You can try build>clean project,  does that make a difference?

Comment: I am facing the issue can any one help to solve this. I m running as administrator.

Comment: @Navaneethan iam also facing the same issue have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution for this.

The problem is in extracting the gradle-xx-all.zip file [ which we will mention in the gradle-wrapper.properties ]

***Solution:***

First go to the **Gradle Setting's --> File -> Settings -> Gradle**

Check for the **Project Level Settings**,

It has been set as **Default gradle wrapper** [ This is to download the gradle version you have mentioned in the gradle-wrapper.properties]

Once the gradle has been downloaded , we could see the gradle has been downloaded in the below location

....gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.8-all\ah86jmo43de9lfa8xg9ux3c4h\gradle-2.8\

[ This is for gradle-2.8 version ]

Go to this place in Explorer and there you could find the gradle-xx-all.zip file **unzip it manually** to the folder gradle-xx [ In this case gradle-2.8 ]

Now again go the Gradle settings and now change the **Gradle Home** present Project-Level settings to the **new unzipped location**.

It worked for me. Try the same. :)

Comment: @Navaneethan, Use this technique